# .apk to iFrame (HTML)

Tags: iframe, apk

I’m trying to make a website that has a .apk file as an iFrame, so that way, you don’t have to install the .apk file. But there are no results when I was doing my research.

I tried using AppSheet and import the .apk from there, and then embed to iFrame. But, there is no such thing as that. I even used appetize.io to use the .apk in a simulator build, but the .apk is not eligible for simulator builds.

Comment: When talking about external services please add a links so we are understand what service/app/program you use. Also please describe in detail what commands, actions and so you you executed, what the result was and where the problem is.